# What is Main log in Android?

Tags: android, android-debug, adb

What is main log in android?And what is its purpose.
I just know that main logs can be viewed by adb logcat -b main.
Can someone explain a bit more about this?

Comment: please explain little more obvious..

Comment: I would like to know about main logs and its purpose in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main log buffer contains log entries e.g. from apps writing them with [`android.util.Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

The other log buffers (events, radio) contain much lower level logging information from the platform.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#alternativeBuffers):

> The Android logging system keeps multiple circular buffers for log messages, and not all of the log messages are sent to the default circular buffer. To see additional log messages, you can run the logcat command with the -b option, to request viewing of an alternate circular buffer. You can view any of these alternate buffers:
>
> - radio — View the buffer that contains radio/telephony related messages.
> - events — View the buffer containing events-related messages.
> - main — View the main log buffer (default)

Comment: what will the main log buffer contain?

Comment: is there a way to choose the buffer to which the logs go?